# Approach to handle data that keeps changing

Tags: algorithm

I am working on a website, and need to present something like 'x% of users who viewed this page bought this product.'

Despite the discussion of the business value, I want to know what would be a acceptable approach to get the data of x%.

I currently have two approaches. Either requires saving the number of users viewed the page and number of users who bought this product.

One approach is to calculate this data on the fly. The pros of this is that it presents accurate data, while the cons is that the wait time for user increases due to the calculation.

The other approach is that for every users viewed or bought this product, calculate the x% amount and persists the data to database. The pros of this is that it allows the users to quickly get the info, while the cons will be a lot of extra calculations, and the data may not be as accurate.

Assuming we expect hundreds of page views per hour, I wonder which is better approach? Or maybe a third approach will work better?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you plan on calculating this on the fly? I can only see it being possible by storing the data and fetching it from a database with every visit.

Comment: Oh, and I assume you meant "on the fly", not "on the flight". Just a heads up.

Comment: @MatthewCliatt on a page visit, get the number of users viewed and number of users who bough this product which are stored in db, and calculate it.

Comment: @MatthewCliatt lol thanks for the heads up.

Comment: So how is that different from the latter approach?

Comment: Assuming you can retrieve page views and purchase numbers from a database, I don't see how the calculation will have a noticeable impact on response time.  Worrying about things like that before you know they are a problem is called "premature optimization".

Comment: what about in-memory cache option?

Comment: By speaking out I think my question is not valid any more, thanks to MatthewCliatt and jimGarrison.

Comment: @jamesdeath123 Another thing to consider is whether you would *want* to show this information to users. Purchases are likely to be much more rare than views, so you may be displaying very low percentages to your users. This may backfire and discourage purchase. A better metric might be the raw number of users who purchased the product.

Comment: @BrianVanover although business values are another discussion, you presented a very good point, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to find a balance between calculating the exact value on every user visit, and having the most accurate display.

You could log every user visit and every purchase in a database, then on every 100th visit or so, perform the calculation. Also log that calculation in your database and have your site pull the information from there, rather then calculate it on every visit.

And depending on how accurate you need to be, and how performance heavy the operation is, you can adjust your interval for calculating the value.

So in all we have that each user's visit increments a value in a database. On the back-end, that value is checked to see if it has went over another interval (so if your interval is every 100, the value is checked to see if its value % 100 == 0). And then you have an operation that only takes place 1/100th of the time a user visits the site, and is still accurate to within the hour (according to your calculation of having hundreds of views per hour).

Having said this, I agree with Jim Garrison's comment about premature optimization. I don't think the operation will have a noticable impact on your site's performance, and if you wanted to be as accurate as possible, you can run the calculation every time a user visits the site or purchases an item.

Comment: interval is a good idea - I am also working on the other problem which you enlightened me. Thanks!